# Trying to Understand Java Dependency Injection with Example

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a database connection library to be used in all my apps. I want to make sure that this library is fully unit tested and so i'm trying to use dependency injection.

I have this class which i want to ensure is tested:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private String dataSourceName;

    public ConnectionFactory(String dataSourceName) {

        if(dataSourceName == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("dataSourceName can't be null");
        }

        this.dataSourceName = dataSourceName;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = getDataSource(dataSourceName).getConnection();

        if(connection != null) {
            return connection;
        }       

        ...
    }

    // Get a datasource object
    private DataSource getDataSource(String dataSourceName) {
        ...
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + dataSourceName);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            ...
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

I want to be able to simply call this class from all my apps with something as simple as this:

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(string[] args) {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory("jdbc/myDataSource");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();
    }
}
```

I've started writing unit tests for this ConnectionFactory, but quickly realized that with my current code I can't mock the DataSource object so it's trying to actually connect to a real data source.

```
@RunWith(Nested.class)
public class ConnectionFactoryTest {

    public class Constructor {

        @Test
        public void shouldThrowNullPointerIfParamIsNull() {
            assertThatExceptionOfType(NullPointerException.class)
                .isThrownBy(() -> { new ConnectionFactory(null); })
                .withMessage("dataSourceName can't be null");
        }
    }

    public class GetConnection {

        public class WithDataSourceAvailable {

            @Test
            public void shouldErrorIfParamIsNull() {
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory("jdbc/myDataSource"); // <-- This is going to fail b/c it's trying to actually fetch a real data source
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

How can I properly use Dependency Injection so that I can write unit tests that don't actually try to connect to a data source?

Comment: "I can't mock the DataSource object" this statement is wrong. It is possible to mock object creation with tools like PowerMock.

Comment: "I can't mock" meaning I don't know how to Mock it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org) I find it easy to use for this type of mocking.